# Use copy() in a foreach loop to copy multiple files php

Tags: php, foreach, copy

I'm trying to copy multiple files from one domain on a web server to another using copy() and looping through a list of files, but it's only copying the last file on the list.

Here is the contents of files-list.txt:

```
/templates/template.php
/admin/admin.css
/admin/codeSnippets.php
/admin/editPage.php
/admin/index.php
/admin/functions.php
/admin/style.php
/admin/editPost.php
/admin/createPage.php
/admin/createPost.php
/admin/configuration.php
```

This script runs on the website that I'm trying to copy the files to. Here's the script:

```
$filesList = file_get_contents("http://copyfromhere.com/copythesefiles/files-list.txt");
$filesArray = explode("\n", $filesList);

foreach($filesArray as $file) {
    $filename = trim('http://copyfromhere.com/copythesefiles' . $file);

    $dest = "destFolder" . $file;

    if(!@copy($filename, $dest))
    {
        $errors= error_get_last();
        echo "COPY ERROR: ".$errors['type'];
        echo "<br />\n".$errors['message'];
    } else {
        echo "$filename copied to $dest from remote!<br/>";
    }
}
```

I get the affirmative message for each and every file individually just as I should, but when I check the directory, only the last file from files-list.txt is there. I've tried changing the order, so I know the problem lies with the script, not any individual file.

The output from the echo statements looks something like this:

```
http://copyfromhere.com/copythesefiles/admin/admin.css copied to updates/admin/editPage.php from remote!
http://copyfromhere.com/copythesefiles/admin/admin.css copied to updates/admin/editPost.php from remote!
http://copyfromhere.com/copythesefiles/admin/admin.css copied to updates/admin/index.php from remote!
```

Etc

Comment: I would recommend first removing the `@` before copy, because you have no legitimate reason to suppress warnings/errors here. Next, check the PHP error log on your server to see if gives you any clues.

Comment: The `foreach` loop is never closed, I assume it is in your actual code?

Comment: Good eye. I forgot to close the `foreach` in the code above, but I didn't make that same error in the actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've modified your code slightly, and tested it on my local dev server. The following seems to work:

```
$fileURL = 'http://copyfromhere.com/copythesefiles';
$filesArray = file("$fileURL/files-list.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
foreach ($filesArray as $file) {
  $fileName = "$fileURL/$file";
  $dest = str_replace($fileURL, 'destFolder', $fileName);
  if (!copy($fileName, $dest)) {
    $errors= error_get_last();
    echo "COPY ERROR: ".$errors['type'];
    echo "<br />\n".$errors['message'];
  }
  else {
    echo "$fileName copied to $dest from remote!<br/>";
  }
}
```

This uses the same fix that Mark B pointed out, but also consolidated the code a little.

Comment: That seems to have done the trick. When I ran your code almost completely unmodified, it worked but it had a double // in between the lowest level directory ("//admin" and "//templates") and the higher ones, so I changed `$filename = "$fileURL/$file"` to `"$fileURL" . "$file"` and that straightened it out. I noticed that you used quotation marks and I didn't. This did not end up making a difference. I don't know what made the difference, but yours worked and mine didn't, so thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unless the data you're fetching from that remote site has leading`/` in the path/filename, you're not generating proper paths:

```
$file = 'foo.txt'; // example only
$dest = "destFolder" . $file;
```

produces `destFolderfoo.txt`, and you end up littering your script's working directory with a bunch of wonky filenames. Perhaps you wanted

```
$dest = 'destFolder/' . $file;
                   ^----note this
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks. I thought of that, but all of the lines in files-list.txt start with a slash, so when it's exploded into the array the looped through, the path/filename is correct. Also, if that were the problem, none of the files would be copying. As it stands, the last one on the list is copying. Here's what the output I'm getting from the echo statements looks like:

`http://copyfromhere.com/copythesefiles/admin/admin.css copied to updates/admin/admin.css from remote!`